# Rails3 activerecord joins can't return values in joined table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have associated two models question and answers, Question model has many answers, So my query was

```
Question.joins("inner join answers on questions.correct_answer_id = answers.id").select("answers.answer")

SELECT answers.answer FROM `questions` inner join answers on questions.correct_answer_id = answers.id
```

in mysql query return correct answer but why rails? I got only

```
[#<Question >, #<Question >]
```

Comment: Question.joins("inner join answers on questions.correct_answer_id = answers.id").select("answers.answer")
.map(&:answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you select using the Question model, you will get a result set that mimics Question models. When you join on the answer - you'll get objects that contain the answer-values inside them - but they still look (on the outside) like a question model... because that's what you technically asked for (by called "Question. ...").

To get the actual Answer objects you could flip the query around and do:

```
Answer.joins("inner join questions on questions.correct_answer_id = answers.id").select("answers.answer")
```

(Adjust as necessary - this code not tested).

OR you could do as sumiskyi suggested and add the call tot h actual column:

```
 Question.joins("inner join answers on questions.correct_answer_id = answers.id").select("answers.answer").map(&:answer)
```

Because that column should be hiding there on that empty Question model, even if you can't see it at the top-level.

Comment: Answer.joins(:question).select("questions.*").find(100) It Only returns the common fields like #<Answer id: 25, created_at: "2010-08-20 18:36:49", updated_at: "2011-09-06 09:50:49">

Comment: @PonnuSamyK What do you mean by "the common fields"? and how does that differ from what you want?

Comment: The "columns that both tables share" (like "created_at") are all you get back.  It *should* return all the items you put in the "select" statement as an array of all those fields (and only those) in the order you listed them - but it doesn't.  This behavior is just wrong - especially if you explicitly convert the AR to an array.  But thank you very much for explaining how to use .map() to get the columns requested with select(), in your 2nd example.

Answer (score 1):

`[#<Question >, #<Question >]` is just array of `inspect`, each element should have an `answer` method.

----- EDITED

You need also select fields from questions table

```
Question.joins("inner join answers on questions.correct_answer_id = answers.id").
  select("questions.*, answers.answer")
```

Comment: no no that is an empty object ..... I need like this #<Question id: 12530, subject_id: 12, chapter_id: 138, answer: 138, question: "<p>Photosynthetic roots are found in...........</p>..."> this is my question object ...

Comment: Hi Still now i not getting answer record 

>> Question.joins("inner join answers on questions.correct_answer_id = answers.id").select("questions.*, answers.answer").first

#<Question id: 3, subject_id: 4, chapter_id: 80, question: "differential equation formed by eliminating ...">
  Question Load (0.4ms)  SELECT questions.*, answers.answer FROM `questions` inner join answers on questions.correct_answer_id = answers.id LIMIT 1

But this is working in mysql prombt

Comment: Answer.joins(:question).select("questions.*").find(100)
     It Only returns the common fields like 
    #<Answer id: 25, created_at: "2010-08-20 18:36:49", updated_at: "2011-09-06 09:50:49">